# Output the lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How to produce outfile.txt from the lists A and B:

```
A = ['x','y','z']
B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

My incomplete code is:

```
with open ('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:
    for a, b in zip (A,B):
        print (a, b, file=outfile)
```

The outfile.txt should look like:

```
x 1 2 3
y 4 5 6
z 7 8 9
```

Comment: To write to a file, you should really use `outfile.write(text)`.

Comment: @jazzpi: No, `print()` like this works fine, that is not the problem here.

Comment: @jazzpi The OP is most likely using Python 3

Comment: @MartijnPieters it works, but I'd say it's somewhat unpythonic. `outfile.write(...)` is IMO the cleaner way of writing to a file as it directly conveys the intention of writing something to a file - with `print` this is only clear once I've mentally parsed the `file` argument, which is easy in this case but can get messy in more complex uses.

Comment: @l4mpi: In Python 3, using `print()` here gives you the additional functionality that that function offers, such as automatically adding a newline and separators for the arguments.

Comment: @l4mpi: This was always intended for the Python 2 `print` statement as well, but that never worked out as the statement was too inflexible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but I still think it's clearer to use `write` in most cases - for simple things like this it's not much of a problem, but for any sophisticated form of output formatting I'd prefer `join` and `format` over messing around with the `print` separators/terminators.

Comment: @l4mpi: I find, for the simple case of whitespace separation, the `print()` call to be more readable. `print(*args, file=fp)` is cleaner than `fp.write(' '.join(args) + '\n')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the `b` list using the `*` splat syntax to expand the values to separate arguments:

```
with open ('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:
    for a, b in zip (A, B):
        print (a, *b, file=outfile)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> A = ['x','y','z']
>>> B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for a, b in zip (A, B):
...     print (a, *b, file=sys.stdout)
... 
x 1 2 3
y 4 5 6
z 7 8 9
```